# How to find grid instance?

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

Here:

http://js-grid.com/docs/#oniteminserting

I read:

```
onItemInserting has the following arguments:

{
    grid                // grid instance
    item                // inserting item
}
```

In my application I have several `jsGrid`. How should I check which one is the 'grid' instance in the callback?

Metacode:

```
onItemInserting: function (args) {
    var grid = args.grid;

    if (grid === 'myGrid') doSomething();
}
```

What is the second term of the comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you find out the grid instance like this:

```
var gridID = $("#grid").data("JSGrid");
```

but I think that you need to spec the name of that instance when you create the grid in the first place like this:

```
$("#grid").jsGrid({
        height: 300,
        name:'Google',
        // etc..
});
```

and then you will be able to compare it with name and do stuff

```
(gridID.name == 'Google') ? doSomething() : false;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `onInit` (http://js-grid.com/docs/#oninit) callback:

```
var gridInstance;

$("#grid").jsGrid({
    ...

    onInit: function(args) {
        gridInstance = args.grid;
    }
});
```

Using data attribute also works, but since this not documented feature it can be broken in any future version (renamed for instance).

Comment: Hey @tabalin, I am using js-grid in angularjs so how can i get instance or load data on change event